# "Synchronizing" two spinners

Tags: android

I have two spinners that I want to be "tied" to one another in a mutually-exclusive sense: If you select an item in one, that item's text turns red and appears at the top, while the other one goes back to displaying the initial ("title") selection (if another item was previously selected), and its text turns white.

This is all done via the onItemSelected listeners:

```
    sectionSpin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {              
            issueSpin.setSelection(0);                                      
            ((TextView) issueSpin.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));  
            ((TextView) arg1).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#E3170D"));
....
```

and vice versa for the "issue spinner". My problem is that, if I'm going from one spinner to the other and I select the top item, the onItemSelectedListener doesn't register because the item being selected is already selected.

I've been told that this is not possible. Or, rather, I've been told that it is impossible for an onItemSelected listener to fire on an item that is already selected. While I realize this is technically true, this problem seems relatively simple and I'm sure there must be a  workaround to produce the desired effect.

I have a few questions regarding some that I'm pondering:

1. Is there any way to set all items in a spinner as unselected, while still displaying one of them?
2. Could I utilize a different type of event (i.e. 'setOnTouchListener', 'setOnClickListener', etc), presumably on the top item, in conjunction with the `onItemSelectedListener`?
3. Should I utilize a different type of event by itself, perhaps on the Views inflated in the spinner themselves, without the `onItemSelectedListener`?
4. Can you help me find a better strategy than those alluded to in the bulletpoints above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a `Spinner`, use a `Button` that visually resembles a non-active `Spinner`. When the button is clicked, show a custom `Dialog` containing a `ListView`. You can use the `setSelection` method and/or the position in the `Adapter`'s `getView` to show which item is currently selected. The `ListView`'s `OnItemClickListener` will get notified that something got clicked regardless of whether the item was selected or not.

When you find which item was clicked, hide the `Dialog` and notify the button-containing `Activity` of this, so that it can update both `Buttons` if needed.

I have implemented something really similar to this using `DialogFragments` and a `DialogFragmentParent` and it works fine.

Comment: But it's critical to the overall design of this app that the menu open like a spinner - i.e. that the options drop down.

Comment: @drewmore I gave an answer that solves the described problem in the question. I first considered sub-classing the `Spinner` and overriding the responsible method (where it's explicit that the `onItemSelectedListener` is not called if the chosen item is the same), but that was not possible, since the method is private. You can emulate the animation if you need it so badly using some other means. However, if my answer doesn't help you because of some non disclosed in the question reasons, then you should edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you consider something like below,

```
sectionSpin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,
            int position, long arg3) {
        updateView("sectionSpin");
     }
}
```

And for other one

```
    issueSpin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,
            int position, long arg3) {
        updateView("issueSpin");
     }
}
```

and now

```
private void updateView(String spinner){
    if (spinner.equals(sectionSpin)){
        //update spinner per requirement

    }
    else{
    //update spinner per requirement
    }

}
```

You can also consider some additional variable or parameters to keep track if the item selected for first time or not.

Comment: This still relies on the onItemSelected() listener, which doesn't fire if the user selects the item that is already at the top.

Answer (score 0):

So, you could make the first item in the spinners not valid selections like "[Choose one]" or "[Select Title]" forcing the listener to fire every time.

This would have the added benefit that you will know user did select something before the next step.

Of course, this would depend on desired application flow.